# Query for window.onbeforeunload

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload( function() { 
      return &quot;Are you sure?&quot; ;
});
```

I want to perform an an AJAX call before the page being unloaded, Is there any other way to achieve this, coz this doesn't work?
Awaiting, thankss :)

Comment: Your JavaScript needs real quotes `"`, not `&quot;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a function as the page is unloading, you can try $(window).unload(), but it can't stop the page from unloading or redirect the user. Also, some browsers block alerts in unload.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"http://localhost:80/ajax.php?", async:false});
  alert('Bye.');
});
```

But your best bet is to do something like:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
   $.ajax({url:"http://localhost:80/ajax.php?", async:false});
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

//I tested this in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox and the ajax call fired successfully each time.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UN2rj/)

Also if you're doing an ajax request on page unload try setting async to false:

```
$.ajax({url:"http://localhost:80/ajax.php?", async:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
window.onpagehide(function() {
    return "Are you sure?";
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: What browsers support that